# JMS TextMessage - not working after deployment to WebLogic

Tags: java, spring, jms, weblogic11g, oracle-aq

I am facing a strange issue after migrating my application from OC4J to WebLogic 10.3.6 server.

My application produces **JMS TextMessage** into OracleAQ queue. It was working fine.
But after deploying the application to WebLogic, produced text messages are getting stored in `USER_DATA_TEXT_LOB` (clob) column instead of `USER_DATA_TEXT_VC` (varchar2) column in underlying queue, whereas the `USER_DATA_TEXT_LEN` is very less (less than 1k chars).

As a consequence, consumer application is failing to dequeue the message and throwing the error: `Payload is NULL`.

Appreciate any help in this regard.

**Update:**

I have tried with jms BytesMessage and it is working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is caused by the version of the `aqapi.jar` and the `ojdbc.jar` being not the same on your `OC4J` and `weblogic` servers.

Try replacing these jar files from your OC4J to your weblogic.

Some version will change type at `500` chars while other will switch at `4000`.. I'm not sure which versions it is tho, but if the first one was working you can try switching the jar files.